# having couple of sub under one command button VBA

Tags: vba, runtime, subroutine

I am designing a user interface that is  supposed to do everything by just clicking on the " Run" button.

It has to do lots of calculation and is getting heavier and heavier. Is there any way that I can define sub under

"Private Sub Run_Click()" ?

I want to make the program faster to be run. I have an error of " runtime error 6 overflow vba"

Also this is the code that includes a heavy loop:

```
Dim NewDate As Long
Dim i As Long
For i = 3 To End_date_Calendar
NewDate = DateAdd("d", i - 3, strDate)
Worksheets("Calcul").Cells(i, "AB").Value = NewDate

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is End_date_Calendar set?
. . .

I don't believe there there is enough code or details to determine what may be overloading.  What does the debug watch expressions say at the error point?

Comment: It is result of another calculation. It is the maximum of one of the columns.